# Finding all parents and checking them in a treeview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, treeview, tree-traversal

I am working with this code on this page: http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html

My problem, is that it want the selection to go in reverse. That is, to check all the parents of the box checked instead of the children.

For example, in the link above, if you were to click **My Documents**, I would want **Documents** and **Libraries** checked as well.

I have tried using parents(), and multiple versions of parent().parent().prev().prev(), and the only thing I came up with that was somewhat functional was this:

```
$(".acidjs-css3-treeview").delegate("label input:checkbox", "change", function() {
    var
    checkbox = $(this),
    nestedList = checkbox.parent().parent().parent().prev().prev(),
    selectNestedListCheckbox = nestedList.find("input:checkbox");

    if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        return selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
    }
    selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
});
```

This would pick only the first parent, and I would need all the parents. I suppose I could construct a loop to keep using this same script, but it seems very ugly.

*What would be a cleaner way of doing what I am looking for?*

Comment: Use [**`.closest`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and pass the `selector` you want to select when getting `nestedList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery's [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method, then checking the immediate children for inputs.  You might need to modify this depending on the layout of your html.  I've demonstrated this with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jdfvnn/1/).

The key part is:

```
var checkboxes = $this.parents().children('input');
```

In full:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var checkboxes = $this.parents().children('input');
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        return checkboxes.prop("checked", true);
    }
    checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: Ok, had to play around with the selectors abit, but now I got it working by adapting your code. Thank you!

Comment: ok, follow up question. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davellan/jt33y9y5/5/

Now when you select multiple checkboxes in some ul, if you uncheck one of them, all of the parents are unchecked too. I want it so that as long as there are "siblings" still checked, the parents should remain checked.

For example, in my fiddle, if you open "Wrestling," "Positions," and then click "Neutral," and "Head and Arm," all of those boxes should be checked. If you uncheck Neutral, only that box goes unchecked. If you uncheck Head and Arm, then Wrestling and Positions uncheck as well.